# OpenGL ES 2.0 Open source front end for GLSL which generates parse tree?

Tags: graphics, compiler-construction, opengl-es, frontend

Is there any OpenGL ES Open source front end of the compiler which generates the parse tree
available?
I checked that 3D Labs provides a front end but it is restricted to OpenGL Desktop version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse tree for what? For GLSL? If yes, then take a look at Mesa3D open-source library. It includes fully functional GLSL parser and preprocessor for both - desktop and ES variants of GLSL.

Comment: yes for GLSL, does it include the same for windows platform? I thought Mesa provided only for linux

Comment: Mesa3D is big library. One part of it deals only with GLSL preprocessing and parsing. You can use only that part on whatever platform you want - it's cross-platform. Of course other parts deals with gpu rendering and are platform specific, but you don't need that.